# Route all traffic to the interface it came from

Tags: networking, routing, iptables

I've set up a Wireguard connection between my PC and VPS Server. I want to use it to port forward to my PC while keeping the clients real IP adress. I think I have everything figured out except the routing on my PC. The Wireguard on my PC is set that it accepts traffic from all IPs (allowedips = 0.0.0.0/0). However when my PC recieves the traffic, it comes through wg0 but all the outgoing trafic goes through eth0. Is there a way to set a route for all the packets that come out of wg0 interface? I have a routing table already created by the Wireguard.

Comment: routes point to IP destinations. in this case, will the traffic you want to send out wg0 be going to a particular IP or a range thereof?

Comment: I don't know the client's IP in advance, The traffic comes through the VPS and has the client's IP. But when my PC wants to send packets to the client, it doesn't use the wg0 (VPN) but uses WAN on my default interface. I need it to use the wg0 for connections that originated from the wg0 interface.

Comment: I don't think this whole "keeping the clients real IP address" thing is going to work out. why are you trying to do that?

Comment: @FrankThomas I have it already figured out. I'm writing a post on Medium that explains how I did that. Long story short I'm behind a CGNAT and don't have a public IP. I still wanted to host a Minecraft server but all the other solutions made it that the Minecraft server would see the VPS' IP and not the client's. If I wanted to IP ban the player, it would ban everyone because everyone was connecting from that same IP. I'll create an answer when I finish writing that post.

Comment: Probably you can ask netfilter to memorize the information about the packet's flow to reuse it later to alter routing rules/tables: part of the solution would start there: https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/netfilter-connmark/ (but the example is for egress while you want to handle ingress).